# Remove lags/gaps in time series data for a particular dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, time-series

I am trying to model a distribution for a particular stock in terms of the amount of times the order book is updated at a certain timeframe.

The issue I am having is in relation to data engineering and pandas. Because I am working only with trading hours and trading days, my dataset has multiple gaps and so the data does not appear continuous. The graph below clearly shows that:

[image]

You can see that the large gaps are weekends and the small gaps are post trading hours.
The small black squares (if zoomed in) would look something like this:
[image]

The dataframe would look like this:

```
    arrivalTime           value           date
    0 days 09:30:02.231     1          2021-05-03
    0 days 09:30:02.981     3          2021-05-03
    0 days 09:30:02.999     99         2021-05-03
    0 days 09:30:10.284     11         2021-05-03
    0 days 09:30:10.293     92         2021-05-03
... ... ...
    0 days 15:59:42.654     82         2021-05-28
    0 days 15:59:42.655     19         2021-05-28
    0 days 15:59:42.651     122        2021-05-28
    0 days 15:59:42.941     199        2021-05-28
    0 days 15:59:44.721     19         2021-05-28
```

The exact thing that I would need is that once a trading day is over, the next day continues exactly after that day has ended. Let me know if there are any questions

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to shift dates to have continuous dates:

Sample:

```
>>> df
         date
0  2021-05-05
1  2021-05-05
2  2021-05-05
3  2021-05-06
4  2021-05-06
5  2021-05-06
6  2021-05-07
7  2021-05-07
8  2021-05-07
9  2021-05-10  # <- 2021-05-08
10 2021-05-10  # <- 2021-05-08
11 2021-05-10  # <- 2021-05-08
12 2021-05-11  # <- 2021-05-09
13 2021-05-11  # <- 2021-05-09
14 2021-05-11  # <- 2021-05-09
```

```
>>> df['date'].min() + df['date'].diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(0)).cumsum().sub(1) \
                                 .apply(pd.tseries.offsets.Day)
0    2021-05-05
1    2021-05-05
2    2021-05-05
3    2021-05-06
4    2021-05-06
5    2021-05-06
6    2021-05-07
7    2021-05-07
8    2021-05-07
9    2021-05-08
10   2021-05-08
11   2021-05-08
12   2021-05-09
13   2021-05-09
14   2021-05-09
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Hey Corralien, thank you for your response. I tried doing what you suggested but it returned all of the times the same:
0      2021-05-03 09:30:00.551614797
1      2021-05-04 09:30:00.551614797
2      2021-05-05 09:30:00.551614797
3      2021-05-06 09:30:00.551614797
4      2021-05-07 09:30:00.551614797
                    ...             
1030   2022-11-16 09:30:00.551614797
1031   2022-11-17 09:30:00.551614797
1032   2022-11-18 09:30:00.551614797
1033   2022-11-18 09:30:00.551614797
1034   2022-11-19 09:30:00.551614797

All of them were  09:30:00.551614797.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would need to skip weekends and when market closes at 4:00 immediately go to the 9:30am from the next day so that the data is continuous.